# Problem with installing package in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, package

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEKH3.png)

I am quite new to Python, and I have encountered a problem. I am trying to install a package "gpaw", but it won't give in. I searched for the error message online, and some answers said that there was some other packages missing and they could be found in the error message.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the error message and hopefully someone can help me with this issue!

Comment: Do have these requirements installed already?

`Requirements

    Python 3.6 or later, 
    ASE (atomic simulation environment), 
    NumPy (base N-dimensional array package), 
    SciPy (library for scientific computing), 
    LibXC, 
    BLAS `
I have taken it from the [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/gpaw/). Have a review, if you the requirements are not in place

Comment: No I had not!!! Thank you for showing me that website, it was really helpful! I installed BLAS and LibXC now and it worked!